# Import module from the current working directory

Tags: haskell, cabal

`init.hs` library module has,

```
module init where
data Suite = Clubs | Diamonds | Hearts | Spades deriving (Eq,Ord,Enum,Show)
```

main.hs, the entry module has,

```
module Main where
import init
main = do
  print (fromEnum Clubs)
```

Both the modules are in the same directory and the directory is not part of cabal path.

On doing `runhaskell main.hs`, it throws error as `main.hs:2:8: parse error on input ‘init’`.

What is the proper way to import module in the current working directory without polluting the global PATH/CABAL variables?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Shouldn't module name start with capital letter?
Replace `init` with `Init`:

```
module Init where
data Suite = Clubs | Diamonds | Hearts | Spades deriving (Eq,Ord,Enum,Show)
```

---

```
module Main where
import Init
main = do
  print (fromEnum Clubs)
```

**Edit:**
As mentioned by [ØrjanJohansen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1088108/%C3%98rjan-johansen):

> Usually, the file should be named after the module name, replacing
>   dots in the module name by directory separators.

[Quote source](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/6.12.1/docs/html/users_guide/separate-compilation.html)

In your case `Init.hs` should be used.

Comment: yours is the right answer... i will make it as accepted.. but still, i am getting the error - `Could not find module ‘Init’`

Comment: @MadhavanKumar, code shown above works for me. Just make sure you save changes.

Comment: @MadhavanKumar Unless you're on Windows, the file name's case also needs to match.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen, good point. I have file named `init.hs` as provided  but I am on OSX.